# $\lVert \int\sigma \rVert \leq \int\lVert\sigma \rVert$

Tags: integration, curves

If $\sigma(t) = (x(t),y(t))$ is a continuous curve in $\mathbb{R}^2$,
I'd like to show that $\lVert \int_{a}^{b} \sigma(t) dt\rVert \leq \int_{a}^{b}\lVert\sigma(t) \rVert  dt$ for all endpoints $a<b$.

I tried using Cauchy-Shwartz but it doesn't work and I don't know how to continue. I'm not sure if the inequality is true, even. Thanks!

Comment: You'd expect the reverse inequality to be true: $\int \lVert \sigma \rVert \geq \lVert \int \sigma \rVert$.

Comment: Think about replacing the integral with a finite sum and the resulting triangle inequality.

Comment: oh, sorry, typo. It's the reverse inequality.

Comment: to be explicit: your notation is $$\int_a^b \|\sigma(t)\|dt = \sqrt{\left(\int_a^b x(t) dt\right)^2 + \left(\int_a^b y(t) dt\right)^2}$$ and not $$ \int_a^b \|\sigma(t)\|dt = \int_a^b \sqrt{x(t)^2 + y(t)^2}dt?$$

Comment: $\lVert \int \sigma \rVert$ is the first thing you wrote. $\int\lVert\sigma\rVert$ is the second thing you wrote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\sigma(t)=\big(x(t),y(t)\big)$. Then, setting $t_{n,k}=a+\frac{k(b-a)}{n}$, we have that
$$
\int_a^b \sigma(t)\,dt=\left(\int_a^bx(t)\,dt,\int_a^by(t)\,dt\right)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{b-a}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n\left(x(t_{n,k}),y(t_{n,k})\right),
$$
and
$$
\left\|\int_a^b \sigma(t)\,dt\,\right\|^2=\left(\int_a^bx(t)\,dt\right)^2+\left(\int_a^by(t)\,dt\right)^2 \\ =\left(\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{b-a}{n}\sum_{k=1}^nx(t_{n,k})\right)^2+
\left(\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{b-a}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n y(t_{n,k})\right)^2 \\=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{(b-a)^2}{n^2}\left(\left(\sum_{k=1}^n x(t_{n,k})\right)^2+\left(\sum_{k=1}^n y(t_{n,k})\right)^2\right)\\ \le
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{(b-a)^2}{n^2}\left(\sum_{k=1}^n\big(x^2(t_{n,k})+y^2(t_{n,k})\big)^{1/2}\right)^2=\left(\int_a^b\big(x^2(t)+y^2(t)\big)^{1/2}\,dt\right)^2=\left(\int_a^b \|\sigma(t)\|\,dt\right)^2
$$
We have used above the Minkowski inequality.

Comment: This might be a tad easier to read if you use the [align environment](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5024).